# Javascript flatten array by same value

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like the following and I want to flatten the array with the same value, to produce textual representations of the data.

```
[
{level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'temperature', value: '37.7'},
{level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'pH', value: '7.5'},
{level: 'green', state: 'very low', key: 'galvanic', value: '34'}
]
```

**Your temperature, pH is very high. Your galvanic is very low.**

I've tried flattening and filtering the array as follows.

```js
function textMaker(alert){
  let flatArray = alert.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
      return acc.concat(curVal.key);
  }, []);

  return "Your <span>"+flatArray.join(", ")+"</span> is <span>quite high</span>.";
}

const alerts = [
  {level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'temperature', value: '37.7'},
  {level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'pH', value: '7.5'},
  {level: 'green', state: 'very low', key: 'galvanic', value: '34'}
]
let redAlerts = alerts.filter((item) => item.level === "red");

console.log(textMaker(redAlerts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see flattening here, but you have to group the items first and then map

```js
const data = [
  { level: "red", state: "very high", key: "temperature", value: "37.7" },
  { level: "red", state: "very high", key: "pH", value: "7.5" },
  { level: "green", state: "very low", key: "galvanic", value: "34" },
];

function textMaker(data) {
  const grouped = data.reduce((groups, current) => {
    if (!(current.state in groups)) {
      groups[current.state] = [];
    }
    groups[current.state].push(current);
    return groups
  }, {});
  

  return Object.entries(grouped)
    .map(
      ([state, group]) =>
        `Your ${group.map((item) => item.key).join(", ")} is ${state}.`,
    )
    .join(" ");
}

console.log(textMaker(data))
```

Comment: This was a very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

you do your textmaker as I understand like the following:

```
function textMaker(alerts) {
  const filteredAlerts = alerts.filter((alert) => alert.level === "red" && alert.state === "very high");
  const keys = filteredAlerts.map((alert) => alert.key);
  if (keys.length > 0) {
    const joinedKeys = keys.join(", ");
    return `Your ${joinedKeys} is at a very high level.`;
  } else {
    return "No alerts matching the specified criteria were found.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, group all the objects with the same 'level' and 'state' then making the text will become an easy task to do

```js
const data = [
  { level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'temperature', value: '37.7' },
  { level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'pH', value: '7.5' },
  { level: 'green', state: 'very low', key: 'galvanic', value: '34' },
];

const data1 = [
  { level: 'red', state: 'normal', key: 'temperature', value: '37.7' },
  { level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'pH', value: '7.5' },
  { level: 'green', state: 'very low', key: 'galvanic', value: '34' },
  { level: 'green', state: 'very low', key: 'suger-level', value: '34' },
];

function generateSentence(data){
const groupedData = {};
data.forEach(item => {
  const { level, state, key, value } = item;
  if (!groupedData[level]) {
    groupedData[level] = {};
  }
  if (!groupedData[level][state]) {
    groupedData[level][state] = [];
  }
  groupedData[level][state].push(`${key}`);
});

// Generate the textual representation
const result = [];
for (const level in groupedData) {
  for (const state in groupedData[level]) {
    const measurements = groupedData[level][state].join(', ');
    result.push(`Your ${measurements} is ${state}.`);
  }
}

const finalOutput = result.join(' ');

return finalOutput
}

console.log(generateSentence(data))
console.log(generateSentence(data1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below code as well. I've handled few exceptions also.

```js
const alerts = [
{level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'temperature', value: '37.7'},
{level: 'red', state: 'very high', key: 'pH', value: '7.5'},
{level: 'green', state: 'very low', key: 'galvanic', value: '34'}
];
function textMaker(alert){
  let flatArray = alert.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
    if(acc[curVal["state"]]) acc[curVal["state"]].push(curVal["key"])
    else acc = {...acc, [curVal["state"]]: [curVal["key"]] }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  return Object.keys(flatArray).map((key) => `Your ${flatArray[key].join(", ")} is ${key}.`).join(" ")
}

console.log(textMaker(alerts));
```